# Java: Read sentences from file separated by a hashtag (#)

Tags: java

I want to ask about printing text on java from file but it is separated by a hashtag(#).

This is the text file example:

```
Chicken#2#Theone#1993#NoneRooster#3#Bone, the roost#1992#None
```

And the format I wanted is:

```
Chicken    |    2    |    Theone             |    1993    |    None
Rooster    |    3    |    Bone, The Roost    |    1992    |    None
```

I don't really know how ArrayList, and files manipulating works in Java and it'll be lovely if you guys can provide a way to do so in detail.

Thanks in advance

Comment: seems like you need to add a next line between None and Rooster

Comment: shouldn't you learn then how to do it? otherwise, you'll ask here in 1h for the solution of the next problem, and so on and so furth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say your file is Text.txt and you have the text in there like this,

```
Chicken#2#Theone#1993#None
Rooster#3#Bone, the roost#1992#None
```

You can easily do it like this,

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("Test.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] words = line.split("#");
            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                if (i == words.length - 1) {
                    System.out.print(formatString(words[i], 20));
                } else {
                    System.out.print(formatString(words[i], 20) + "|");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    static String formatString(String word, int length) {
        return new String(new char[5]).replace('\0', ' ') + word + new String(new char[length - word.length()]).replace('\0', ' ');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, sir. I'll try and read through the code :)

Comment: Sir, i want to ask about this statement
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)

is it to tell the end of file ?

Comment: @KevinTan br.readLine() reads the line from your text file. Lets say you have 5 lines in your text file. Then the while loop will iterate 5 times. Until there are no lines anymore (br.readLine() will return null when there are no lines ). Thats the meaning of that line.

Comment: thanks a lot sir. But what if I want to print them out with space like in my question? I'm still not so sure about where can I put the formatting.

Comment: @KevinTan I have added a method for formatting Strings. Please check the edited code

Comment: Although i still don't understand how the method works, but i'm really thankful and appreciate that you wanted to answer me :) Thanks a lot sir.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your input is (with lines)

```
Chicken#2#Theone#1993#None
Rooster#3#Bone, the roost#1992#None
```

then you can try with this

```
String input = "Chicken#2#Theone#1993#None\n" +
            "Rooster#3#Bone, the roost#1992#None";
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(input))){
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] cols = line.split("#");
            System.out.print(cols[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < cols.length; i++) {
                System.out.print("|" + cols[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, sir. I'll try and read through the code :)